# I want to replace a file with existing file in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6Sgg.png)

Iam already uploaded a file in a database. Now i want to replace a file. So can anyone can tell me the logic to implement to do.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you need to update the first file as disabled and add a new file as enabled.

Do you want to do this change on .net platform or you just wonder the sp logic?